# SignUP with Google not working

Tags: google-signin

I have implemented Sign in with google, and its working properly.
Now, I want to implement Sign up with google.

I am using below links:

1) https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth?scope=email+profile&response_type=token&client_id=?&redirect_uri=?
Here, I have passed the client_id and redirect_uri

2) https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/userinfo
with other parameters like access_token, token_type and expires_in

But, the second link is going not found

Please tell.. where I am going wrong.

Answer (score 0):

You probably should not be directly calling those endpoints but instead using the Google API client library to sign in and get user info [as described here](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/). Starting from that exact snippet and replacing your client ID should get you to the point where you have the user profile that you can use to pre-populate a sign-up form.